# Cost at Each Level of a Recursion Tree

Tags: recurrence-relation

Given a recursive function $T(n)=T(a_1\cdot n)+\dots +T(a_k\cdot n)+\Theta(n)$ such that $\forall a_i: 0<a_i<1$, what is the most general thing I can say about the sum of the cost of the nodes at each level of the recursion tree?  I've looked at a few, and for the ones I've looked at it's always come out to $(a_1+\dots +a_k)^i$ where $i$ is the level in the tree.

Could anyone explain this?  If it matters it's in the context of trying to prove that $T(n)=\Theta(n) \Leftrightarrow a_1+\dots +a_k < 1$

Comment: Sure $(a_1+\dots +a_k)^i$ is wrong.

Comment: Well, more specifically it's come out to $(a_1+\dots +a_k)^i \cdot \Theta(n)$.  But like I said, that's only the trees I've looked at, specifically the ones where $a_1+\dots +a_k<1$.

Comment: No is more closer to this: $[{1 \over a_1 } + ... + {1\over a_k}]^i$, it's a little bit complicated, but if you want prove the other thing, seems you don't need this.

Comment: But I stated that all the $ai$ meet the condition $0<a_i<1$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right!

The work $W$ at each node (of level $i$), splits into $Wa_1, Wa_2, \dots, Wa_k$ at level $i+1$.

If you add them up, you get that the total work at level $i+1$ is $a_1 + a_2 + \dots + a_k$ times the total work at level $i$.

Of course, this assumes that your $\Theta(n)$ is some exact $cn$, but this argument is good enough to prove that $T(n) = O(n)$. Proving $T(n) = \Omega(n)$ is trivial.

btw, I recommend you look at [Akra-Bazzi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akra%E2%80%93Bazzi_method) as a useful tool, if you are interested in such questions.

Comment: So this only holds when all the $a_i$ are between $0$ and $1$, correct?  Also, does this still hold for any function $\Theta(n^x)$?  It seems that it would, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @RobertS.Barnes: It(the upper bound proof) will work for any $a_i$, as long as the extra term is $\theta(n)$. No, it won't work for any $\theta(n^x)$.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  If the $a_i$ sum to a value $\geq 1$, then the algorithm will be at least $\cal{O}(n \lg n)$, since at least $n$ work is being done at each level of the tree.

Comment: @RobertS.Barnes: Yes, I am talking about the proof that work done at each level is $(a_1 + a_2 + \dots + a_k)^{i} \times \Theta(n)$. That does not contradict the fact that $T(n) = T(0.5n)+T(0.5n) + \Theta(n)$ is $\Theta(n \log n)$. Why do you think it does? Perhaps we are talking different things...

Comment: OK, I think I just misunderstood you.  I know it's not part of the original question, but why does it only hold when the extra term is $\Theta(n)$ and not for any extra term $\Theta(n^x)$?

Comment: @RobertS.Barnes: I think there was a misunderstanding there too (probably by me this time). Assuming the $\Theta(n^x)$ is just $n^x$, The work done at level $1$ is $n^x(a_1^x + a_2^x + \dots + a_k^x)$, this is not the same as $n^x(a_1 + a_2 + \dots + a_k)$. Of course, the proof can probably be modified to give $n^x(a_1^x + a_2^x + \dots + a_k^x)^i$ instead of $n^x(a_1 + a_2 + \dots + a_k)^i$.

Comment: Thanks, I think if I have time I'll pursue that as a separate question.